# Add vector tile sources to QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapbox, vector-tiles

Is it possible to add vector tile sources (using MapBox's protocol buffers format, or GeoJSON, or otherwise) to QGIS? If so, how?

(My question is a bit similar to [Can the new Mapbox Vector Tiles be used as a QGIS basemap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60880/can-the-new-mapbox-vector-tiles-be-used-as-a-qgis-basemap) but isn't restricted to MapBox sources, and isn't just about basemaps or OpenLayers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this plugin is still work in progress, and only works on Linux, but allows you to read mapbox vector tiles : https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin

The plugin mentioned above is now being develop from another developer and runs on Windows and Ubuntu. It's still experimental but a working version is expected in June.

Answer (score 6):

Vector tiles are now supported directly in QGIS 3.14+:

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html

https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/crowdfunding/vectortile-qgis/

Comment: It would be good to add in here what is and isn't supported, rather rely on links that have a tendency to break.  I note that the change log link is at the moment just a holding page with no details...

Comment: I can add vector tiles in 3.16, following the top answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/connecting-qgis-to-os-vector-tile-api

Answer (score 3):

**QGIS 3.4 Answer**

There is a plugin called: `Vector Tiles Reader`  which can do this in QGIS 3.x:
[image]

Once added, it will be located **Vector  Vector Tiles Reader  Add Vector Tiles Layer...**:
[image]

And then you can provide your info and add the layer:
[image]

Comment: Did anyone try this with mapbox?? https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_STYLE_ID/wmts??access_token=...

Comment: @watbywbarif you just add using https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8,mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2.json?secure&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN

Answer (score 2):

I got this working with MVT (Mapbox Vector Tiles) by referencing the URL format documented at https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/vector-tiles/

1. In QGIS, right click on `Vector Tiles` in the Browser pane and select `New Generic Connection`
2. Add a Name for reference - e.g. `Mapbox Streets`
3. Add a URL in the following format (be sure to replace `YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN`): `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN`
4. Click Ok to save, then add the vector tiles as a layer by double clicking on it.