# OSM Map quality deteriorates when changing CRS - QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, basemap

I have a problem with basemaps for my drawings in QGIS.

By basemaps I mean OpenStreetView, Google Maps etc. I'm aware that most of them (if not all) are natively set in EPSG:3857, and they look just fine in that CRS. However, when I'm required to use a different coordinate system in my project - for example EPSG:32630 - they understandably get a little distorted.

Are there any basemaps that would accommodate to the chosen CRS without the loss of quality?

Below I enclosed screenshots of OSM in 3857 and 32630:

3857:
[image]

32630:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by this question: `"Are there any basemaps that would accommodate to the chosen CRS without the loss of quality"`?

Comment: Well, that is kind of a long shot but, are there any base maps that wouldn't lose quality when changing CRS? Probably something vector-based?

Comment: Of course it would probably be much less detailed.

Comment: Read about vector tiles.

Comment: check this [Add vector tile sources to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138512/add-vector-tile-sources-to-qgis)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Do you have any thoughts on the question #2?

Comment: Hi @Pawel, stack exchange questions should only have one question. Please edit this question to only include one, and if you have more questions you can ask in another post.

Comment: How are you adding the basemaps?

Comment: I've added them through QuickMapServices and HCMGIS plugins.