# Connecting QGIS to OS Vector Tile API

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, vector-layer, ordnance-survey

How do I bring Ordnance Survey's OS Vector Tile product directly into QGIS via their API (https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/vts/overview)?

It feels like this should play very easily with the vector tiles layer add, but having tried both the plain URL with authentication separate, or with the key embedded, get errors both with generic and ArcGIS style connections. All the examples they have are for building web apps, but I'm looking at high granularity analysis instead so they don't work for me. (Examples [here](https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-vector-tile-api/vts-3857-basic-map), tech spec [here](https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/vts/technicalSpecification)).

Comment: Improvement to QGIS at 3.16 helped https://markallengis.medium.com/improved-vector-tile-support-in-qgis-3-16-9be2bf3cfbdd

Answer (score 6):

Adding the OS Vector Tile API to QGIS should be relatively straight-forward process.

You will need QGIS 3.16 or higher (as this in when the enhanced VTS Support was added).

Go to `Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Tile Layer`. Click `New` and select `New Generic Connection...`

In the Vector Tiles Connection dialog – you will need to add the following:

Name: **OS Vector Tile API**
URL: **https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf?key=INSERT_API_KEY_HERE&srs=3857**
Min. Zoom Level: **5**
Max. Zoom Level: **18**
Style URL: **https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/resources/styles?key=INSERT_API_KEY_HERE&srs=3857**

Comment: I get an error of the style URL is there an alternate?

Comment: @mappingdom that style works for me. Have you made sure to insert your API key in the style URL?

Comment: @TheoF thanks for reply, added key etc. but still same error. URL works in browser so something going on with QGIS

Answer (score 2):

Already consumed Ordnance Survey vector tiles but from Zoomstack product using Maptiler plugin https://twitter.com/ThomasG77/status/1276092119770378240 except there are not key for access contrary to your use case.

When adding the layer, the Maptiler plugin will complain about "Access error ocurred. Please confirm your API-key".
It's because I do not use Maptiler product in this case and the plugin expects a key I do not need to provide.
At the end, although it throws this message, your vector tile are added as a layer and work.

Comment: Thank you; so I can get the zoomstack loading nicely, but can't even get it to throw the right error with the VTS API. If I put in the https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts?key={with API}, I get a format error against '_is_vector_json' (obviosuly isn't!), and if I do it without, I get a longer error on the decoder which looks like a missing value (I assume it's trying to parse from the API authentication error message). I think I may be out my depth on this, but really appreciate the reply.

Comment: Limitation of the Maptiler plugin. If the URL to the service end with `.json`, it considers it can be parse. Otherwise, it supposes it's a pbf, hence your decoder message errors.  See code https://github.com/maptiler/qgis-maptiler-plugin/blob/99a8d5623dcdfd1a30a4d95fa5e0f13827f509dc/browser_mapitem.py#L114

Comment: 3 choices to bypass the issue: 1) use a proxy that call the VTS endpoint API with an URL ending with .json 2) edit the plugin content. In this case, you could replace `if url_endpoint.endswith(".json")` with `if url_endpoint.endswith(".json") or 'https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts' in url_endpoint` 3) Edit https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/04529f07abb4c4331ef538c254754538 with your key and save with json extension and point to this JSON (served from a server eg http/https URL)