# Adding a Vector-tile layer

Tags: qgis, wms, vector-tiles

When trying to add Vector Tiles-layer I get the response

Coding "application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile" is not supported (kodning application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile stöds inte)

I use add a WMS-layer and when I press connect I am moved to another tab called 'Tile' uppsättning (probably 'Tile'set) with two rows with two EPSG CRS codes but both are greyed out and when the cursor is above so is there a message "coding application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile is not supported"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Vector tiles would not be a WMS layer. It would be a vector tile layer. Check out the answer in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/connecting-qgis-to-os-vector-tile-api

Comment: ok when adding a vector tile new generic connection its not even connecting? It only says not a valid or known source

Comment: Make sure the URL is in the correct format, type=xyz&url=http://example.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector_tiles/vector_tiles_properties.html

Comment: Thanks its was the format that needed to be manually changed

Comment: Excellent. I have posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector tiles would not be a WMS layer. It would be a vector tile layer. Check out the answer in:

[Connecting QGIS to OS Vector Tile API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/connecting-qgis-to-os-vector-tile-api)

With the URL in the correct format: type=xyz&url=example.com{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector_tiles/vector_tiles_properties.html

Comment: Vector tiles are in scope for WMS

Answer (score 1):

You can use Geoserver and WMS service to generate on-the-fly MVT, that Openlayers can handle:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html