# QGIS, Ordnance Survey Vector Tiles, CRS and zoom levels

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, ordnance-survey

I'm trying to use the Ordnance Survey vector tile API in QGIS. A starting point is [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/connecting-qgis-to-os-vector-tile-api), but I'm having real problems with the CRS, and zoom levels.

If I specifiy srs=3857 in the URL, eg `https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf?key=INSERT_API_KEY_HERE&srs=3857`, QGIS from somewhere gets the idea that the maximum zoom level is 14, reporting that 'Information from provider' says Zoom levels 0 - 14. I can zoom in further than this, but no additional data is fetched.

If I don't specify srs=3857, or do specify srs=27700, the data appears to be 27700. But QGIS thinks its 3857 and draws the UK covering most of the western world. QGIS still thinks the max zoom is 14, but with the UK now so much bigger than it really is this is fine, because zooming to 14 gives me all the detail I need. Just not in the right place or at the right scale!

Setting maxzoom in the vector tile dialogue box has no effect.

Looking at the JSON for the API endpoint, the 27700 version specifies lods from 0 to 15 with maxzoom 15, the 3857 version specifies lods from 0 to 19 with max zoom 18. So where is QGIS getting the idea that the max zoom for 3857 is 14, and how can I persuade that this is not the case? I'm guessing that as the vector tile dialogue requires the URL of the tiles, not the URL of api endpoint, QGIS never sees this information. If I try to enter the endpoint URL I just get a URL error.

I have also tried using the MapTiler plugin and pointing this to a modified GL JSON file, itself pointing to a modified version of the file delivered by the API endpoint. However, MapTiler only seems to preserve one query parameter, and I need to include both key and srs. If I put srs first I get nothing because authentication fails. If I put key first I get data in 27700 (the default). Any suggestions as to how I can get the OS data with all zoom levels, and with a match between what QGIS thinks the CRS is and what the data is actually using?

UPDATE:
It seems this is at least partly related to a [bug introduced in QGIS 3.24](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47933). Reverting to the LTR version allowed maximum zoom to be set manually for the layer, which got things working with 3857. I get the impression that the use of other projections for vector tiles isn't currently supported.

Comment: This seems like two distinct questions: 1. the zoom level issue, and 2. the projection issue. I recommend editing your question to target one of these issues, else your question is likely to be closed as [needs more focus](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions#:~:text=Needs%20more%20focus,of%20the%20problem.). You can create an additional question for the remaining issue.

Comment: I suspect it isn't two distinct issues, but two symptoms of the same issue. Zoom levels supported by the API is related to projection. Somehow communication between QGIS and the API is getting muddled and there is confusion about which projection is requested / returned and which zoom levels that projection supports