# Ordnance Survey vector maps not connected to QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, ordnance-survey

Following the query here:

[Connecting QGIS to OS Vector Tile API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/connecting-qgis-to-os-vector-tile-api)

I tried to make the steps as per this thread but for the 3.12 version.

The situation looks like you see below:
[image]

I have an error despite usage correct API key and link provided in the query above.

However by looking at the technical specs on their website

https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/vts/technicalSpecification

it looks like the link doesn't appear anymore.

Has something changed since the last query or am I wrong with my approach?