Is it possible to see a MVT layer of GeoServer inside QGIS?
I've installed GeoServer with the kartoza/geoserver docker container, this GeoServer already comes with the MVT layer plugin installed... So I've created the MVT layer with a PostGIS table, I know it works fine because I can access this MVT layer from a frontend web app using Maplibre. The MVT layer has the following format:
http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:mylayer@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
Even though it works fine in Maplibre, when I try to use this layer in QGIS going on Layer/Add Layer/Add Vector Tile Layer it doesn't work. It tells me that the style is not found inside the database:

Could specific configurations in my database be causing this problem? Is there a known method to successfully view MVT layers from GeoServer in QGIS?

Vector Tiles Plugin? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138512/add-vector-tile-sources-to-qgis

@Mapperz I think I'm already using the Vector Tiles Plugin when I go to Layer/Add Layer/Add Vector Tile Layer, but just adding the link of my tile layer in it doesn't work... My guess is that it's expecting something different inside the database when it says Style not found in database... I'm not sure if that's something I'm supposed to put inside the database or if the Geoserver MVT layer is not compatible with QGIS.

I think the message is just misleading - try inverting the y parameter like in the OpenLayers example http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:mylayer@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf

@BerndLoigge Cool, that solved my problem. Just adding {-y} at the end and leaving the Style URL blank was enough to make the MVT layer appear on the map. Thanks!

@BerndLoigge, even being trivial I think you should write the solution as an answer.

I think the message is just misleading - try inverting the y parameter like in the OpenLayers example
http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:mylayer@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf
